# Double Render Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Right let me explain a little in code, I'm trying to get the user to stay on the edit action until the user is completely valid. So far I have the following code in the application controller:

```
def check_privileges!
  redirect_to "/users/edit" until current_user.valid?
end
```

registrations_controller.rb

```
before_filter :check_privileges!, only: [:new, :create]
```

jobs_controller.rb

```
before_filter :check_privileges!, only: [:index]
```

Now when I click on the link to jobs#index it gives me the following error. I cannot see a redirect in jobs#index

```
AbstractController::DoubleRenderError in JobsController#index
```

No clue how to sort this, I've tried `and return` but I cannot figure this out. I've been doing this all day as a user has to complete their profile before they have full access to the application.

Any clues, this is really bugging me now and I have no smart programming friends to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is `unless` not `until`...  `until` will cause a loop of `redirect_to` (thus leading to multiple redirects) if the `current_user` is not valid.

Try:

```
def check_privileges!
  redirect_to "/users/edit" unless current_user.valid?
end
```

Comment: OMG after 13 hours staring at a screen how could I have missed that! D'oh & Thanks

Comment: No worries man - sometimes another set of eyes is all you need. :)

Comment: Look forward to the day when I can do pair-programming in a job